# unity says: The type or namespace name 'Slider' could not be found. Even though everything should work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im new to unity and i have a problem with my AudioMixer. I created a AudioMixer and called it MainMixer. I also created a Slider by the name VolumeSlider so the MainMixer would make all the audio source actually quieter or louder when i drag the VolumeSlider. I wrote a script for that. (ignore its name)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class MenuEvents : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider volumeSlider;
    public AudioMixer mixer;

    public void SetVolume()
    {

        mixer.SetFloat("volume, volumeSlider.value");


    }


    }
```

[image]

[image]

I tried to solve it by myself but couldnt figure out anything

Comment: As the error suggests you are missing a `using UnityEngine.UI;` ... also `SetFloat("volume, volumeSlider.value");` should probably rather be `SetFloat("volume", volumeSlider.value);` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the namespace that contains the `Slider` class . At the top of your script you must add `UnityEngine.UI` namespace.

You can do that by adding the next line at the top:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i managed to get rid of this problem, thanks again